# Create a Read-Only Partition on Flash Drive

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, boot-partition

I am currently trying to partition my flash drive so that it has three separate partitions: one is bootable, the other is a read-only partition containing a decryption software, and the third is an encrypted partition.

My questions are:

How do I create a small read only partition?

If I have three different partitions on the flash drive, will it still be bootable? (it currently contains live-cd ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points you should consider:

- In what OS or device you want to read this flash drive?
  If the idea is always booting the Ubuntu Live to use the other partitions - thats one thing. If you want compatibility to other OS and devices (ie. media players), things get more tricky.
  You can format the 'read-only partition' with cramfs or squashfs / for Linux-based readers it would be fine, for windows no.
- What do you mean by read-only? Just preventing acidental overwrite is one thing - but physical protection is hardware dependent.
  Some flash drives have 'low level' configuration tools available on the web that allow them to be identified as two devices, one being a CD-ROM. But that's not partitioning, its a hardware feature.
  Most OS will warn you if you try to overwrite a file marked as read-only - that can be enough for preventing users from doing crap.